# Direcionar para determinada galeria usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho 3 galerias sendo representadas em JavaScript, cada uma das galerias mostra 4 fotos principais com a opção "ver mais" ao lado. Quero que ao clicar na opção, abra uma nova janela mostrando todas as fotos da pasta img com o o nome atribuido a galeria 1. Por exemplo, a galeria 1 possui fotos com nomes "foto1, foto2, foto3, foto4, foto5, foto6...", quero que ao clicar em "ver mais" direcione para outra página com todas as fotos da galeria 1 nela. e se clicar no "ver mais" ao lado da galeria 2, carregue todas as fotos da galeria 2, que possuem, por exemplo, nomes de "outrafoto1, outrafoto2, outrafoto3" etc... poderiam me ajudar ? Eis os codigos: A função que carrega as imagens principais nas galerias:

```
window.onload = function(){

        var galeria = new Array();

        var imgs = $("#gallery");
        var x = 1;

        while(x <= 3){

            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='eight columns'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+x+"</h4>"

        for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            galeria[i] = "foto"+x+"_"+(i+1)+".jpg";
        }
        for(i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            imgs.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+galeria[i]+"' class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }

        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        x++;
        imgs.innerHTML += "<a><div id='link' onclick='maisGaleria("+x+");'><p>Veja mais</p></div>";
    }
```

A função que da opção "ver mais" que nao direciona nada, apenas sobrepoe as divs anteriores:

```
function maisGaleria(n){

    var galeria = new Array();
    var imgs = $("#gallery");

        imgs.innerHTML = "<div class='row'>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='six columns'>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria"+n+"</h4>";

        for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            galeria[i] = "foto"+n+"_"+(i+1)+".jpg";
        }

        for(i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            imgs.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+galeria[i]+"' class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }

        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Estou com bastante dificuldade de entender a pergunta, creio que alguns exemplos ajudariam. Tipo: "ao digitar `1,3,2` no campo de texto, o elemento `#gallery` tem de receber as imagens `foto1_1.jpg`, `foto1_2.jpg`, `foto1_3.jpg`, `foto3_1.jpg` ... `foto2_3.jpg`" (somente um exemplo, não entendi nada da lógica que você quer). P.S. Use sempre `var` ao declarar suas variáveis, no seu código o `i` por exemplo é uma global; e se possível, corrija a identação do seu exemplo de código, esse trecho onde o `for` aparece ainda dentro do `while` me confundiu (parece que está fora).

Comment: Corrigi ! Ficou mais facil de compreender ? Obrigado !